# Call TPath.GetDocumentsPath from within a Service Application

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-services

I want to access some files in the `MyDocuments` folder when I run my service on WIndows. 
The documentation says that in case of Windows `GetDocumentsPath` returns:

- `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\My Documents` (XP)
- `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\My Documents` (Vista or later)

In my case I get `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents`. Is it some kind of link to the Documents directory in Windows? Btw, I see no `Documents` folder in the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile` path.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/9325/ What are you expecting to happen? Why would the local system account have a documents folder? Why are you running your service as local system anyway? Presumably you are aware that this is considered bad practise. Also be alive to file system redirection. If your process is 32 bit then remember that system32 is redirected to SysWOW64.

Comment: Now, you also say, "the `MyDocuments` folder". But which one do you mean. There are many, one for each user. Are you aware of this?

Answer (score 2):

The Documents folder is a **per-user** folder.  `TPath.GetDocumentsPath()` returns the Documents folder of the user account that is associated with the calling thread.  But if your service is running under the `SYSTEM` account, not a particular user account, you cannot use `TPath` to obtain the path of any user-specific folder.

In order for a service to retrieve a user's Documents folder (or any other user-specific folder), the service must either:

1. be running as the desired user to begin with, not the `SYSTEM` account.
2. if running as the `SYSTEM` account, obtain a token for the desired user account, and then pass that token to [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx).

   - If the user is currently logged in, use [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833.aspx) and [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383838.aspx) to locate the user's login session, and then use [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840.aspx) to get that session's user token.
   - If the user is not currently logged in, but you have the user's login credentials, you can login to the account with [`LogonUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) to get the user token, and then load the user's profile into memory with [`LoadUserProfile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281.aspx) before querying the folder path.